# How to ask for forgiveness of Past Qaza Salaat

Tags: salat

As-Salam-o-Alaikum,

How do someone ask for forgiveness of his/her past qaza salaat (prayers that were not offered) when she/she doesn't know how many (hundreds) of prayers has been missed.

JazakAllah khair

Comment: How were these salaat prayers missed?  Because one slept or forgot etc, or because one couldn't be bothered to pray or missed them on purpose?

Comment: You can create a Kaza Catch Up Plan using following App. It will calculate all your missed prayers and you can follow the plan to offer your Kaza Namaz. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.muslimprayertimes.missedprayers.kazasalatcatchup

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the answer to my comment, there are 2 scenarios here (according to the fatwa linked below):

1. You missed salaah unintentionally, i.e. you fell asleep, you forgot etc
2. You missed salaah intentionally, i.e. you couldn't be bothered, you didn't want to pray etc

For the unintentional scenario, you can make up the salaah by praying asap as soon as you realise.  For the intentional scenario, you can't make up for it by praying, you have to do lots of good deeds, pray lots of optional prayers, ask for forgiveness a lot, do a lot of charity work etc, in the hope that you do enough to get forgiven.

Here is the [full fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/111783).

Answer (score -5):

I believe Allah has provided us with an opportunity to be able to make up for years of missed prayers. After doing my own research, my solution was to pray qaza for one day's prayers on Laylat-al Qadr. I have explained my process from thinking and planning to action, all here. i'A you will be able to catch the next Laylat-al Qadr and Allah will accept your qaza prayers for all the rakat you have missed:  https://www.facebook.com/notes/murat-kurt/ramadan-2018-looking-back-and-future/10156467646199532/

Comment: I wonder if this is not considered as spam or promotion for your FB-Site/Blog/Wahtever

Comment: Millions of Muslims, especially the ones who became Muslim later or started practising  later in their life are asking themselves the same question: how can I make up for years of prayers, given that salat will be one of the very first things we will be questioned for. Do you have an answer for them?

Comment: Yes a good one not such a baseless statement. Nobody knows when laylat al-Qadr is and who guarantees you that Allah deals this way?

Comment: So you deleted my comments, worked with Medi1Safi to make sure my response to all questions on this matter -which millions of people are trying to find a solution- have been down voted until you posted an answer? Here is my question to you: if I was right with my reasoning and you prevented people from benefiting it, do you think you will not be held responsible?